# Execute Postgresql Stored Procedure in PySpark

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, pyspark, aws-glue

I am working on Pyspark in AWS Glue
I want to execute Stored Procedure/Function on Postgresql Database
Is it possible?
What is the syntax? Is there any special package needed?

Ankur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try using a module like pg8000 to run this function
2. You can also try calling the postgres function like you would select data from a specific table using the spark read function with jdbc as the format. Considering glue uses pyspark in the back end, i would imagine just giving the function name instead of a table name, should do the trick. Just remember to add the jdbc driver to your glue job

eg: You can do this in spark

```
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/db").option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").option("query", "SELECT * from  function()").option("user", "user").option("password", "password").load()
```